# Let $u=(1,0,1)$ and $X = \{w \in \Bbb{R}^3 | w \times u = 0\}$ Is this a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $u=(1,0,1)$ and $$X = \{w \in \Bbb{R}^3 | w \times u = 0\}$$ 
Is X a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$?

If so, find a spanning set for $X$ and give a complete geometric description.

So I get that the vector must be perpendicular to $u$, thus being a vector perpendicular to the $y$-axis, but i'm not sure if this constitutes a vector subspace of $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: I've edited your post to include MathJax. Please verify that it is correct.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! If possible, do you have the answer?

Answer (score 1):

In order to check that $X$ is a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^3$, you need to check that it's non-empty (what's a vector that *always* cross-products to $0$?), that it's closed under scalar multiplication, and that it's closed under addition.

That is, if $c$ is a real number and you've got $w \times u = 0 = v \times u$, the relevant questions are

- Is $(cw) \times u = 0$?
- Is $(w + v) \times u = 0$?

The answers will follow from the basic properties of the cross product.

Comment: Thank you, but what about for the spanning set, and geometric description. I get the subspace part and it makes sense.

Comment: Does w x u = 0 not mean that w is parallel to u?

Comment: Everywhere I look is saying other wise.
When the cross product of two vectors is zero, the two vectors are parallel seems to be the prevalent opinion.